# C++ : include string before the vowels in a sentence

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, insert

I'm a beginner in c++ and I'm training on exercises.

I'm stuck on one part. I would like to insert the string "CH" in front of each vowel in a sentence.

I first tried using string::replace, but it was not the best idea.
I would like to use string::insert to do this.

However, I can't seem to use it properly in a loop to tell it that the [i] is the desired position

Do you have any advice for me?

```
    string message = "you have a secret message to decrypt";
    string newMessage = "";
    string InsertMessage = "CH";

    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
        if (
            message[i] == 'a' ||
            message[i] == 'e' ||
            message[i] == 'i' ||
            message[i] == 'o' ||
            message[i] == 'u' ||
            message[i] == 'y')
        {
            //newMessage = message.replace(i, 1, InsertMessage);
            newMessage = message.insert(i, InsertMessage);
        }
    }

    cout << newMessage << endl;

    return 0;
```

Comment: Build your output string incrementally with `+=`

Comment: When you detect that the **first** character is a vowel in `you have a...` and you change it to `CHyou have a...`, which character should you inspect next???

Comment: I see zero need for *either* `replace` or `insert` in this code. build your new message by appending chars from your old, with the added condition that, in the event the current iteration char is a vowel, you append InsertMessage on the string before appending the current char.

Comment: *Do you have any advice for me?* My advice would be to use debugger to go step by step through your code, inspecting the content of string at each loop iteration, as well as which index is currently in the loop. You should quickly notice the issue.

Comment: As others mentioned, you are overengineering this and tying yourself up in knots by trying `replace` or `insert`.   Just start out with an empty output string, loop through the original string, and add the characters to the output string when you detect a vowel.

Comment: When you're struggling with how to so something think on how you would solve the problem if you had a pencil, some paper, and someone shouting inputs at you. What you would do almost always directly maps to an algorithm you can use on the computer, though there are often ways the computer can do the job better. If you don't already know a better way to do the job, do it the stupid human way and look for patterns you can exploit to reduce the amount of work needed for a smarter version 2. If you need a version 2.

Comment: Note: Computers are really good at doing stupid things fast, so sometimes stupid will outperform smart for small runs of inputs, and these "small runs" can turn out the be unexpectedly long.

Comment: Note it might help to not think about the input as a sentence, but instead as a stream of independent characters. If you have someone shouting characters at you the natural solution would be to write CH on the piece of paper if the character is a vowel and then always write the character.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
newMessage = message.insert(i, InsertMessage);
```

does not make a sense at least because it changes the original string message.

I can suggest the following approach shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string message = "you have a secret message to decrypt";
    std::string newMessage;
    std::string InsertMessage = "CH";
    const char *vowels = "aeiouy";

    auto n = std::count_if( std::begin( message ), std::end( message ),
        [vowels]( const auto &c ) { return std::strchr( vowels, c ); } );

    newMessage.resize( message.size() + n * InsertMessage.size() );

    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    do
    {
        auto i = message.find_first_of( vowels, pos );

        if (i == std::string::npos)
        {
            newMessage += message.substr( pos );
            pos = i;
        }
        else
        {
            newMessage += message.substr( pos, i - pos );
            newMessage += InsertMessage;
            pos = i;
            newMessage += message[pos++];
        }
    } while( pos != std::string::npos );

    std::cout << newMessage << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
CHyCHoCHu hCHavCHe CHa sCHecrCHet mCHessCHagCHe tCHo dCHecrCHypt
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I'll work on it :)

Comment: This is not an answer. Please follow the guidelines in the help center.